# Performance profiling in acceptance/ functional tests

Tags: selenium-webdriver, profiling, codeception, acceptance-testing

I use a simple acceptance test that does the following:

- Loads the start page of the website;
- Performs authorization attempt;
- Performs logout attempt;
- Performs register attempt.

Each functionality is tested in several steps, for example -

```
...
$I->wantTo('Try to login with right credentials'); // step 1
$I->amOnPage('/user/login');                       // step 2
$I->fillField('#login-form-login','admin');        // step 3
$I->fillField('#login-form-password','admin');     // step 4
$I->click('#login-form button[type=submit]');      // step 5
$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/user/admin');            // step 6
...
```

I want to know how long performed each set of steps/ individual step.

Since all the functions are collected together in one test, the result of running this command is present a report that shows the time that was spent on the entire test as a whole.

```
codecept run acceptance --html
```

Is it possible in Codeception make group of steps (some markers, may be..) and show time that spent for perform these groups?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add the following code to the `FunctionalTester` or helper class:

```
class FunctionalTester extends \Codeception\Actor {
    ...

    private $firstTimeTag;
    private $secondTimeTag;

    public function markFirstTimeTag()
    {
        $this->firstTimeTag = new DateTime();
    }

    public function markSecondTimeTag()
    {
        $this->secondTimeTag = new DateTime();
    }

    public function calculateTheDiffFor($step)
    {
        echo $step.": ". round($this->secondTimeTag->getTimestamp() -
                $this->firstTimeTag->getTimestamp(), 3). " s\n";
    }
    ...
}
```

And then use this actions in Cept/ Cest files:

```
$I->wantTo('Try to login with right credentials'); // step 1

$I->markFirstTimeTag();

$I->amOnPage('/user/login');                       // step 2
$I->fillField('#login-form-login','admin');        // step 3
$I->fillField('#login-form-password','admin');     // step 4
$I->click('#login-form button[type=submit]');      // step 5

$I->markSecondTimeTag();
$I->calculateTheDiffFor("Login attempt");

$I->seeCurrentUrlEquals('/user/admin');            // step 6
```

The output can be seen in the Jenkin's logs, for example.